# bijective parametric curve

Tags: calculus, inverse, parametric, inverse-function, parametrization

Given the parametric function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ with  $f(x,y) = (3x+2y,4x+3y)$. Is $f$ bijective?

So if you look at any given point $(\dot{x},\dot{y}) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ the system of linear equations should always be solvable:

(1): $\ 3x+2y = \dot{x}$

(2): $\ 4x+3y = \dot{y}$

Do i get $f$ is surjective from that? What about $f$ injective?

Comment: $A=\begin{bmatrix}3&2\\4&3\end{bmatrix}$ has determinant $1$, so it is invertible, so it is injective. Since it has full rank, it is surjective.

Comment: How do i get the inverse function?

Comment: Invert the matrix.

Comment: @Arjihad Either by calculating the inverse matrix $A^{-1}$ or by solving the system with your favourite technique, having $\dot x$ and $\dot y$ as parameters. It really depends on your background.

Comment: $x= 3 \dot x-2 \dot y\\y= 3 \dot y-4 \dot x$

Comment: The title "bijective parametric curve" is a little misleading, as the map you've defined has nothing to do with curves.